# Declaration vs definition in C

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Consider the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;
}
```

As far as I know, `int a;` is a definition, as it causes storage to be reserved. Citing the C standard (N1570 Committee Draft — April 12, 2011):

> **6.7/5 Semantics**
>   A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> ...

Here comes the question: the compiler may optimize away the storage, since we are not using the variable. Is then `int a;` a declaration then? And what if we do a `printf("%p", &a)` in `main(void)` - certainly now the compiler **has to** allocate storage, so is the concept of declaration/definition dependent on whether you later use the identifier or not?

Comment: A definition is always a definition, even if not used (and even when the compilers doesn't actually emit code or reserves space for it).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well the standard is a bit ambiguous, it certainly says: *causes storage to be reserved...*. And then throughout the standard the term is used interchangeably, e.g. they call `int* p;` a *declaration*. The whole discussion started [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33159989/3093378)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: @RahulTripathi No it's not a dupe, I would like an answer according to the standard, that's why the language-lawyer tag also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text you quoted from 6.7/5 is actually meant to be interpreted the other way around than what you have done: the text is saying that definitions cause storage to be allocated.

The text which specifies that `int a;` is a definition is elsewhere.

C is defined in terms of an abstract machine. There is storage allocated in the abstract machine.   Whether or not any memory is allocated on your PC is unrelated.

Comment: The thing that confused me is the fact that they refer to e.g. `const int *ptr_to_constant;` as a *declaration*, see 6.7.6.1/3 (page 130 of the document I linked). And technically it's correct, since a definition can also be a declaration...

Comment: @vsoftco All definitions are declarations so that terminology is correct (although perhaps misleading)

Comment: Yeah that's what's going on probably. But the abstract machine is certainly the right way of thinking about it. But what about `int f(); main(){} int f(){return 0;}` Isn't the `int f(){return 0;}` only a definition? Or you are talking about variables?

Comment: @vsoftco, no this are also a declaration of the functions `main` and `f`, but declarations without "prototype".

Answer (score 2):

> Is then `int a;` a declaration then?

Yes.

In fact, **every definition is also a declaration**. A variable can have only one definition, but could have multiple declarations.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a;
```

This is a definition
There is a memory allocated for variable `a`

```
extern int a;
```

This is a declaration.
Memory is not allocated because it is not defined.

Once a variable is defined you can use the address of it which is totally legal.

Answer (score 0):

A declaration introduces an identifier and describes its type, be it a type, object, or function. A declaration is what the compiler needs to accept references to that identifier. These are declarations:

```
extern int bar;
extern int g(int, int);
```

A definition actually instantiates/implements this identifier. It's what the linker needs in order to link references to those entities. These are definitions corresponding to the above declarations:

```
int bar;
int g(int lhs, int rhs) {return lhs*rhs;}
```